# I'm trying to figure out what is my problem with moving playerX to the screen? I want to move playerX += .1 but i'm getting error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

```
import pygame

#intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship (1).png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('ship.png.png')
playerX = 400
playerY = 490

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

# game Loop
running = True
while running:
    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    playerX += .1

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I fixed the question-text formatting, and it works for me.  Maybe it was the indentation of the call to `player(playerX, playerY)` and `pygame.display.update()` ?

Comment: {import pygame} {pygame.init()} {screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))}
{pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")}{icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship (1).png')}{pygame.display.set_icon(icon)}{playerImg = pygame.image.load('ship.png.png')}{playerX = 400}{playerY = 490}{def player(x,y):}
{screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))}{running = True}{while running:}
             {screen.fill((0, 0, 0))}
 { playerX += .1for event in pygame.event.get()}:
    {  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:}
            running = False


        {player(playerX, playerY)}
     {pygame.display.update() }

Comment: it say "DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))"

Comment: Information that is critical to your question must be edited into the question.  As you can see, comments are virtually useless for code.

Comment: You can get rid of the warning by `screen.blit(playerImg, (round(x), round(y)))`

Comment: thankyou for you help Rabbid76 and all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

> it say
>
> "DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float). Implicit conversion to integers using int is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python. screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))"

The warning is related to the coordinate parameter of [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). Floating point coordinates, would mean that the origin of the [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is somewhere in between to pixels in the window. That doesn't make much sense. The coordinates are automatically, implicitly truncated and that is indicated by the warning.
Use either [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to convert the floating point coordinates to integral numbers:

```py
def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerStand, (round(x), round(y)))
```